# Using JavaScript to call method of Android activity

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I understood from the following guide on how to call simple functions from HTML -> JavaScript-> Android
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Can you help me fix the following? (error at line startactivity)

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:+918979"));
//Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:+6512567"));
startActivity(i);
```

Error:

```
02-09 10:13:40.615: W/dalvikvm(1194): Pending exception is:
02-09 10:13:40.615: I/dalvikvm(1194): Java.lang.NullPointerException:
02-09 10:13:40.615: I/dalvikvm(1194):   at Android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.Java:3190)
02-09 10:13:40.615: I/dalvikvm(1194):   at Android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.Java:3297)
02-09 10:13:40.615: I/dalvikvm(1194):   at sstpl.app.CallActivity.onClickCall(CallActivity.Java:34)
```

Comment: i don't get your problem, could you explain it a little better?

Comment: ok. sorted the problem

mContext.startActivity(i); //does the trick

Comment: to explain...my webview loads html...the button uses javascript...the javascript function calls android activity. A toast is very simple. But calling intents is a little tricky...and using context we can call intents also. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted the problem mContext.startActivity(i);